# How do I create a user defined exception that would system exit if not handled? (Exception class seems insufficient.)

Tags: python, exception

The python `Exception` class is supposed to be used for all user defined exceptions. Documentation also says it is used by all *non-system-exiting* builtin exceptions. I need to create a user defined exception that will **system exit** if not handled. In quick tests, calling a method (while **not** using `try`...`catch`) that raises my user defined exception doesn't cause an exit. In debugging, I can see that the exception is 'received' by the python interpreter, but it doesn't cause an exit.

Comment: Accepted answer is correct. I'm leaving the question here because I think it adds clarification to behavior of user defined exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure? Exceptions do normally cause the program to exit. The following never reaches the `print` statement.

```
class MyError(Exception):
     pass

raise MyError

print("survived")
```

If you see different results, it must be because you are doing something else. Add your code to your question if you still can't see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: You're right. It's more complex. I'm trying to create a wrapper around a 3rd party module to catch several of the module's exceptions and essentially "simplify" them with my own exceptions.

Comment: I hope this did the trick, then. Naturally it will also catch system exceptions triggered in the try block (whether by the module or by your own code). A propos, are you aware of the syntax `raise <Error> from <exception>`? Could come in very handy for your use case.